# How do I get nlargest rows without the sorting?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I need to extract the n-smallest rows of a pandas df, but it is very important to me to maintain the original order of rows.

code example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 10, 8, 11, -1],
    'b': list('abdce'),
    'c': [1.0, 2.0, 1.5, 3.0, 4.0]})
df.nsmallest(3, 'a')
```

Gives:

```
   a  b    c
4 -1  e  4.0
0  1  a  1.0
2  8  d  1.5
```

I need:

```
   a  b    c
0  1  a  1.0
2  8  d  1.5
4 -1  e  4.0
```

Any ideas how to do that?

PS! In my real example, the index is not sorted/sortable as they are strings (names).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Simplest approach assuming index was sorted in the beginning

```
df.nsmallest(3, 'a').sort_index()

   a  b    c
0  1  a  1.0
2  8  d  1.5
4 -1  e  4.0
```

---

#### Alternatively with `np.argpartition` and `iloc`

This ***doesn't*** depend on sorting the index.*emphasized text*

```
df.iloc[np.sort(df.a.values.argpartition(3)[:3])]

   a  b    c
0  1  a  1.0
2  8  d  1.5
4 -1  e  4.0
```

Comment: Sorry for not being specific enough, have amended my question. Index not sortable

Comment: Works like a charm, tnx a lot!

Comment: Maybe `df.sort_values('a').head(3).sort_index()
`